# How to listen to a variable when it changes so that it updates the value in the components involved?

Tags: angular

I think I'm doing bad practice, so I would like you to guide me please.

I have a variable in a provider.

```
@Injectable()
 export class SharedService  {
 public mynumberservice:any=0;
```

and in two components: `MainComponent` and `MenuComponent`t I modify the value of this variable with a setTimeout, this is the best way?

```
this.SharedService.mynumberservice=2;
```

Thanks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmmbi4?file=app/main.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify value directly. Add a service method that does that.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService  {
  public mynumberservice: number = 0;
  mySubject = new Subject();

  setMyNumber(value: number) {
    this.mynumberservice = value;
  }

}
```

and in your component you can set it this way:

```js
  this.SharedService.setMyNumber(2);
```

For getting the latest value you can use observable from your service to emit new values and "listen" to them. Add `this.mySubject.next(value)` line:

```js
  setMyNumber(value: number) {
    this.mynumberservice = value;
    this.mySubject.next(value);
  }
```

and in your component you can do:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'main',
      template: '{{ SharedService.mySubject | async }}',
      styles: []
    })
```